# Standalone socket.io and Websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I need to build a socket.io server that will intercept incoming connections from an app which is not stored in the same directory as the server.

The client side app does not contain node.js, thus I'm trying to use a websocket :

```
Telnet.Socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:3000');
```

My node.js server does not need a http server but must be a standalone socket.io app. Thus, I've tried the following code :

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connexion entrante');
});
io.listen(3000);
```

Unfortunately, the server part does not seem to get the Websocket connection request. My firefox says :

Firefox cannot establish a connection with the server at adress ws://127.0.0.1:3000/.

What am I missing ?

Thx in advance !

Comment: Socket.io is an abstraction over websockets, with added functionality(long-polling etc), but the initial connection uses `XMLHttpRequest`. In order to communicate with Socket.io, you need a Socket.io client.

Comment: Or use a pure websocket server, like [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws).

Answer (score 0):

socket.io need client use socket.io to connect because it use many kind of connection. For connect websocket only you can use `ws` node module

Comment: Managed to get it to work with ws indeed, thx for your help, until the next question^^